# "unwinding": { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false } not working in v3.4 aggregate $lookup

Tags: mongodb

i am trying to run a aggregation pipeline with lookup stage . 
the pipline is taking to long so i decided to optimize the pipline in the unwind stage by removing documents with empty arrays.

the docs on the mongo site suggest that this should work but in v3.4.

my lookup stage looks like this

```
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "abc",
            "localField": "abc_id",
            "foreignField": "abc_id",
            "as": "abc_info",
            "unwinding": { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false }
        }
     }
```

im getting the errror

```
    "arguments to $lookup must be strings, unwinding: { 
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false } is type object"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) only `$unwind` supports `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`, not the `$lookup`. BTW, Mongo's optimizer adds the `$unwind` to the `$lookup` stage for you, so feel free to add the `$unwind` in a separate stage. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) is more material about query optimization + your specific example of `$unwind` + `$lookup`

Comment: so if i didnt want to unwind empty lists i would have to add a match stage after the lookup to reduce the number of documents i would unwind.

Comment: @elisharobinson I believe it is true.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of there no "unwinding" option in `$lookup` .

`$unwind` is another **different stage** in `aggregation`

make these changes in the query:

```
 {"$lookup": {
    "from": "abc",
    "localField": "abc_id",
    "foreignField": "abc_id",
    "as": "abc_info",
}},
{$unwind: {
    path: "$abc_info"      //preserveNullAndEmptyArrays is false by default.
}}
```

it should work then.

Comment: this solution is not optimised, might not work on a large dataset